# copy contents of registered variable to other hosts

Tags: ansible

I'm running the following tasks (I'm going to paste only the relevant asks in the whole role):

```
- name: create certificate private key
  community.crypto.openssl_privatekey:
    path: "/root/client/{{ item }}.key"
    type: Ed25519
    backup: yes
    return_content: yes
  register: privatekey
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
  when: "'prometheus1' in inventory_hostname"
```

What I'm trying to do it copy the contents of the variable to another host.

```
- name: copy private key to host
  copy:
    content: "{{ privatekey }}"
    dest: /root/private_key_from_var.key
```

(I'm not at this point worried about filtering or distributing the key to the corresponding hosts - just want to understand why the content itself isn't being copied.

So weirdly enough, the only host it works on is 'prometheus1', the one where I'm actually running the task that generates the keys. There I get the a generated file `private_key_from_var.key` with all the contents I'm expecting.

The exact same file on the other two hosts is just an error report coming from ansible itself:

```
{"results": [{"changed": false, "skipped": true, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", "item": "prometheus1", "ansible_loop_var": "item"}, {"changed": false, "skipped": true, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", "item": "breitband", "ansible_loop_var": "item"}, {"changed": false, "skipped": true, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", "item": "status1", "ansible_loop_var": "item"}], "msg": "All items completed", "changed": false}
```

I'm not sure why I am unable to copy this content on any host I wish to, but it's rather strange.
I also tried the same thing using a template and invoking the variable directly in the jinja file, but to no avail.

Any ideas?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when: "'prometheus1' in inventory_hostname"

This is only running the task when the hostname matches prometheus1, and explains why you're getting it only on the prometheus1 host.

Comment: Thank you. I marked it as an answer. I'd figured it out already, actually, but I simply couldn't find the question unfortunately, I'm not sure why.
Indeed, in order to access the variable, I needed to use hostvars, as in:
``hostvars['prometheus1']['privatekey']['results'][0]['privatekey']`` for the first private key and so on :)